# Grails: Facing difficulty to create list using Ajax

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new in Grails.There has four basic domain class say A, B,Q,T and another is transaction class Tr. There has only one controller named Trcontroller. The classes and controller are as follows :

```
    class A {
        String aName
        String aId

        static constraints = {
            aName(nullable:false, blank:false)
        }
        static belongsTo =[tr:Tr]

        public String toString() { userName }
        String getname() { userName() }

        }

    class B{
     String b
        static constraints = {
        }
        static belongsTo =[q:Q]
    }

    class Q{
        String q
        String qtype
        static constraints = {
        }
        static belongsTo =[b:B]
    }

    class T {
      String t

         static constraints = {
        }
         static hasMany = [q:Q]
    }

    class Tr {
        A a
        B b
        Q q
        Q qtype
        T t
        static constraints = {
        }

    }
class TrController {

    def index() { }
    def dropdown(){}
    def userlist=User.get(params.id)


}
```

Now I want to create simple drop down list from class A in a dd.gsp page. The code is as follows:

```
 <g:select name="User_name" from="${UserInstance.toString() }" value="${UserInstance?.toString()} }"/>
```

on change the drop down value a result will show from all the domain class in the same page.

Try to create drop-down list (on dd.gsp page) but it shows an error:

```
Class:   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message :   No signature of method: practice00008.TrController.getParams() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Please guide me how to solve these problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def userlist=User.get(params.id)` called in static context, when Grails creates this class. Not for a request.

You have to create an action for you `dd.gsp` (`/dd` I guess? or maybe your current `dropdown` action do the job? then put following code into this action), and load this data from here, like:

```
def dd() {
  def userlist = User.get(params.id)
  render view: 'dd', model: [userlist: userlist] 
}
```

or simply:

```
def dd() {
  [userlist: User.get(params.id)] 
}
```

Comment: i'm talking about Action. see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#understandingControllersAndActions Currently you have two actions: `dropdown` and `index`

Comment: Hello @Igor Artamonov Sir, Using your code drop-down occur with null value but not show database value.

Comment: check what it gets from db for specified id. and make sure that you pass such id in url, of course